# Does anyone have the demo for exchange mailbox in iOS?

Tags: ios, email, exchangewebservices

Hello  I am searching how to use EWS in iOS.
I want to implement Exchange (maybe like the system mail app) in my mailbox app. But now after my hard searching, I still can't find the way to start. Does anyone have a demo or API? (Preferably a demo). Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following link:

[Developing Mobile Apps with Microsoft Exchange Web Services](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/OUC-B304#fbid=)

Or [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/?platform=iOS).

Comment: Thank you .
The 2 links I have read before. I just followed the Microsoft Graph API and download a demo from git hub.
I can succeed to get the mail list form Microsoft. However, I don't know how to set the server address like the Mail.App. Now I want to do the function something the Mail.App.  Do you have any suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Mail.APP for IOS. However, I suggest that you can refine your question and list some code for this.